# Validate statement that can appear inside if statement

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate a statement that can appear inside if statement? Is regex a correct tool for it? I tried it using:

[`^((?:\w+(?:\s*)?(?:[!<>=]=?=?)(?:\s*))+\w+\s*(?:&&|\|\|)?\s*)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/opYPUT/1)

String to test:

```
Valid:
ds > 33
ds < dd
d >= 32
d >= d
ds <= dd
ds <= 2
ds == ds
ds === ds
ds != d
ds != 1
ds !== d
ds
!ds
ds > 32 && ds < 32
Invalid:
ds > 32 && ds < 32 ||
ds < dd && || ds < 22
```

But failing to do so. Can someone shed some light on this topic?

Comment: You should write a parser instead of using regex. Regex is used to parse regular language, not code.

Comment: If you're looking for a regex-only solution, however, does [`^ *!? *\w+\s*(?:(?:={3}|!={2}|[<>!=]=|[<>]) *\w+ *(?:(?:(?:&{2}|\|{2}) *)!? *\w+ *(?:(?:={3}|!={2}|[<>!=]=|[<>]) *\w+ *))*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/opYPUT/2) work for you?

Comment: Are you dynamically composing these statements? If not, you should just use a linter of some kind to check your code for issues like these

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your use case, I'm guessing you're dynamically composing boolean expressions and worried about parameters of empty length. If you did want to write a regex of some kind, it'd probably make more sense to create one to detect errors rather than validate correct structure, like so:

```
(&&|\|\|)\s*(&&|\|\|): detect two boolean operators in sequence
(&&|\|\|)\s*$: boolean operator with nothing after it
^\s*(&&|\|\|): boolean operator with nothing before it
```

So `/(&&|\|\|)\s*(&&|\|\|)|(&&|\|\|)\s*$|^\s*(&&|\|\|)\s*/` would detect those issues. If you want to go beyond that and check for illegal comparison operators, you can do something along these same lines.

Comment: ? That's not what the regex is checking for. It's looking for two operators in a row, as in `if a == 10 && || b == 5`. Your example is two boolean expressions in a row, which is definitely fine